# lambdas fail to log to CloudWatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-xray

Situation - I have a lambda that:

- is built with Node.js v8
- has `console.log()` statements
- is triggered by SQS events
- works properly (the downstream system receives all messages, AWS X-Ray can see those executions)

Problem:

- this lambda does not log anything!

But if the same lambda is called manually (using "Test" button) - all logging statements are visible in CloudWatch.

My lambda is based on this tutorial: https://www.jeremydaly.com/serverless-consumers-with-lambda-and-sqs-triggers/

A very similar situation occurs if the lambda was called from within another lambda (recursion). Only the first lambda logs stuff (started manually), but every next lambda in the recursion chain does not log anything.

an example can be found here:
https://theburningmonk.com/2016/04/aws-lambda-use-recursive-function-to-process-sqs-messages-part-1/

any idea how to tackle this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your lambda function declaration? And double check: IAM **lambda execution role**; Double check **Basic Settings**: Lambda Invocation time; and Maximum Memory.

Comment: thanks for your response. This actually started to work properly today (with no code or configuration changes whatsoever). Maybe I just was struck by some service updates that introduced a bug?
anyway - my lambda declaration was the same as in mentioned blog posts. all settings in IAM had to be correct because those lambdas were executed and messages were received by the end system. memory consumption was around 60% of the limit. the invocation time around 20% of the max limit.